# Can a core constant expression contain an ignored reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

When compiling the following sample program with godbolt.org online compiler, Clang-9.0.0 and MSVC v19.24 both report errors at lines marked (1) and (2). The error message says that expression `(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&x), 1)` does not evaluate to a constant. But it does, doesn't it?

GCC-9.2, on the other hand, compiles this sample with no errors.

```
#include <memory>

int x;

enum
{
    Value = (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&x), 1)    // (1)
};

template <int N>
struct Test
{
};

Test<(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&x), 1)>     t;   // (2)
```

The question is: does `(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&x), 1)` evaluate to a constant?

Comment: It is explicitly forbidden: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.15

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A core constant expression cannot contain a `reinterpret_cast` even if its value is discarded (so MSVC and Clang are right to reject the code). See C++17 [expr.const]/2.15:

> An expression `e` is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions: ... a `reinterpret_cast`

According to the rules of the abstract machine, the `reinterpret_cast` must be evaluated. See [expr.comma]/1:

> A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right; the left expression is a discarded-value expression. Every value computation and side effect associated with the left expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the right expression. ...

It is clear that the mere evaluation of the `reinterpret_cast` is enough to make the expression not a core constant expression, even though it doesn't affect the result at all.

This is different from situations where the cast is genuinely not evaluated:

```
enum {
    Value = 1 || reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&x);  // OK
}
```